# Voting "wrongly."

Tags: word-usage

The title of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N9cka850qA) is "Interview Douglas Murray (EN)" (beginning about 1:40).  In it, the interviewer says: "European citizens too often vote wrongly."

At first glance, the word "wrongly" appears odd.  After looking around, I couldn't find any reasons why this use would be incorrect.  It's an adverb that is used in other examples, such as, "A person wrongly convicted of a crime," or "I wrongly assumed something."  Even if you take "wrongly" and place it in front of the verb "voted" it still seems off.  If the word "incorrectly" is substituted, the phrase seems OK: European citizens too often vote incorrectly.

Grammatically-speaking, "wrongly" can be used in this way.  My question; is there another reason why this usage isn't supported?  Or if it has been used before, why isn't it used more often?

Comment: this might [help](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386154/i-read-it-wrong-wrongly?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Does Douglas Murray actually use that phrase though, or has it come from the German media company who put the video up? I would say *vote the wrong way*. I don't think *vote wrongly* has to mean *vote when they shouldn't* but it can sound that way, and I think that's why we usually say *I got the wrong answer* or *I said the wrong thing* etc.

Comment: To me "vote wrongly" implies that they have voted other than in accordance with the voting procedure. That is they have spoiled their ballot papers. Voting for a candidate or outcome the speaker does not like is not "voting wrongly" it is expressing a contrary opinion (don't get me started on Brexit). Voting for a candidate or outcome other than the one they intended to support is voting in error (and  no one, probably not even the voter, would ever know). Finally voting fraudulently (Vote early vote often?) is voting illegally which is much more serious.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the expression from a syntactic point of view.  "Wrong", however, can be ambiguous if not sufficiently qualified (eg, with "from a syntactic point of view").  The use of the term in the original quote is highly ambiguous and open to a vast range of interpretations, though in the context of the clip it appears to mean "for the wrong side of an issue", with the implication that the voters are uninformed.

Comment: @Ubi hatt That question/answer does provide some valuable context (thank you!) but it has a problem. One of the top-voted comments insists that "wrong" is correct because it's a "flat adverb" (good), but the objection to "wrongly" is shaky (the NGram has such tiny units as to not be significant; the association of "wrongly" but not "wrong" with "inherent evil" feels selective).

Comment: To me "vote wrongly" sounds 'wrong' because it is ambiguous. Does it mean they "voted other than in accordance with the voting procedure" as suggested by BoldBen above?  Does it mean that they voted differently from the speaker's preference; e.g. they voted 'Yes' & the speaker thought they should vote "No"?

Comment: He doesn't say it - it's a completely false question, just a mistake by a German speaker.

Comment: @Minty - If you listen to the recording, it's fairly clear that the interviewer means the votes were cast for the "wrong" people, or for the "wrong" side of a referendum.  In other words, the interview is assuming that the interviewee (and, at least for the interview, the interviewer) prefer one political stance to others, and those others are "wrong".

Comment: @HotLicks yes I realise that, but the interviewer is German. He is not a native speaker so his use of this phrase doesn't reflect on the English language. That's what I meant by saying it's a false question. The native speaker avoids this use, as I would and as (based on the comments) other native speakers would. It seems we all feel that saying *to vote wrongly* would suggest that there was something wrong in the act of voting itself.

Comment: @Minty - I don't find the usage particularly non-idiomatic, and I don't know that the interviewer was not a native English speaker -- his accent to me sounded pretty much BBC British.

Comment: @Hotlicks OK well if you don't find it non-idiomatic, fair enough. If you can't hear that that's a German accent, I don't know what to say.

Comment: @Minty - To my US ear Einblick sounds like pure BBC.  Actually a little less "starchy" than normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Wrongly* isn't wrong here, but someone seeing the title of the video without understanding its context might be rightly confused for two reasons: *wrongly* isn't an expected collocation and without the context *wrongly* and *wrong* are ambiguous.

---

***Wrongly* was not the collocation you were expecting.**

*Wrongly* may be unexpected here because of the common use of the [flat adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb) form *wrong*. A flat adverb describes an adverb that lacks the -ly suffix that marks most adverbs derived from adjectives. The flat adverb looks indistinguishable from an adjective, which is why prescriptive grammarians in the 18th century discouraged its use. (Compare: "I ran quick" and "I ran quickly." The first is used commonly in informal speech but discouraged by many editors and grammarians in formal contexts.)

Despite such discouragement of flat adverbs in general, *wrong* as a flat adverb is more common than the adverb *wrongly*: the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has instances of the adverb *wrong* 10125 times (out of 93754 results for *wrong*), and *wrongly* appears 1645 times.

These results suggest that *wrongly* would be a less expected collocation for  English users. A Google search for "voted wrong" and "voted wrongly" confirms that "voted wrong" has around 25,000 results and "voted wrongly" has around 10,000. COCA has three results for "voted wrong," all in spoken situations on CNN or CBS news/current event shows. "Voted wrongly" does not appear, indicating that it might be less common in journalistic or media use. As a result, readers and listeners might expect *wrong* rather than *wrongly* and perhaps they'd even expect another adverb before *wrongly*. These expectations can affect initial judgments of appropriate usage.

---

**Both *wrongly* and *wrong* have ambiguous meanings here**

A given action or event can be done wrong(ly) in several ways. Did someone vote wrong(ly)

- procedurally, that is, they mishandled the ballot in some way?
- politically, that is, they voted for a candidate or issue that the speaker considers wrong?
- criminally, that is, they voted when they were not eligible to vote
- ethically, that is, they approach the act of voting in a way the speaker considers invalid or immoral

There are more possibilities. Both *wrong* and *wrongly* have issues with ambiguity, such that having this as the title of the video is less precise than using a more specific adverb or qualifying the adverb with more explanation. So why did the video preparer (Einblick) go with *wrong* or *wrongly*?

---

**The context determines how *wrong* and *wrongly* are understood**

Consider the larger context. One reason *wrong*/*wrongly* is used is because the term appears several times as an adjective and adverb to describe voting habits fairly early in the video. I type out the relevant snippets that, indeed, start at 1:40 in the above video:

> (Murray) voting the wrong way, voting for the wrong parties ...
>
> (Einblick) this is a concept of (rote?) voting wrong
>
> (Einblick) people have developed this idea that people vote wrongly when they haven't been informed yet in a proper way

Einblick is caught up in the usage and repeats it, while Murray moves on to explicate why the claim that people vote wrong(ly) is a simplification of opponents' political arguments and issues. "Wrong" becomes one of the key charges in this discussion, but it takes listening quite carefully to both Murray and Einblick to figure out exactly how the *wrongly* in the video title should be taken and whether Einblick's paraphrase is correct.

It's a matter of opinion whether such a video title is enticing (people will watch because they want to know why Murray says people vote wrongly), misleading (it's unclear exactly what "wrongly" means), or both, and that uncertainty that may be at the root of your discomfort with its usage here.

Comment: As you said, "The first ("wrong") is used commonly in informal speech but discouraged by many editors and grammarians in formal contexts."  Einblick sounds to me to have adapted BBC speech style, and the folks at BBC are known for their prescriptive formality.  What's common usage in the US would not be particularly applicable.